# Hide void option from menu in DocuSign envelope view from c# for all users

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk, envelope-schema

Hide void option from menu in DocuSign envelope view.
Can I do this using C# DocuSign SDK?

To hide Void option for user usingfor all the users whether user is participant or not.
Envelope is being accessed using CreateRecipientView end point of docusign.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Focused View](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) with a bit of JS/HTML to do that.

Recommend you download the full (right most) [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) for C# and then search for "Focued View" to see how it works.

Here is what the HTML/JS looks like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Signing</title>
        <style>
            html,
            body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }

            .docusign-agreement {
                width: 75%;
                height: 800px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="agreement" class="docusign-agreement"></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

<p><a href="/">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SupportingTexts.ContinueButton)</a></p>
@Html.Raw("<script src='https://js.docusign.com/bundle.js'></script>")

<script>
    window.DocuSign.loadDocuSign('@ViewBag.IntegrationKey')
        .then((docusign) => {
            const signing = docusign.signing({
                url: '@ViewBag.Url',
                displayFormat: 'focused',
                style: {
                    /** High-level variables that mirror our existing branding APIs. Reusing the branding name here for familiarity. */
                    branding: {
                        primaryButton: {
                            /** Background color of primary button */
                            backgroundColor: '#333',
                            /** Text color of primary button */
                            color: '#fff',
                        }
                    },

                    /** High-level components we allow specific overrides for */
                    signingNavigationButton: {
                        finishText: 'You have finished the document! Hooray!',
                        position: 'bottom-center'
                    }
                }
            });

            signing.on('ready', (event) => {
                console.log('UI is rendered');
            });

            signing.on('sessionEnd', (event) => {
                /** The event here denotes what caused the sessionEnd to trigger, such as signing_complete, ttl_expired etc../ **/
                console.log('sessionend', event);
            });

            signing.mount('#agreement');
        })
        .catch((ex) => {
            // Any configuration or API limits will be caught here
        });</script>
@{


  [1]: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-focused-view/
```